# Conflicting Devise and restful controller routes | Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rails-routing

I'm working on a Rails 5.2 project that uses Devise to manage a `User` model. I want users to be able to sign themselves up, and allow administrators to create accounts on their behalf. I've set up the `User` model with Devise, and generated scoped controllers (and views) for the resource. This covers the self-signup aspect, and to cover the administrator-initiated sign-up, I've created a `users_controller` as a standard restful controller, and in the routes, set up a resources route respectively. This seems to work for everything except the `users#create` action route conflicts with the route created by the `devise_for` for `users/registrations#create` (see generated routes below). This causes `users#new` form submissions to be incorrectly handled by the Devise `users/registrations#create` instead of `users#create`.

What would be the best way of making the `*#create` routes unique?

**routes.rb**

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: 'users/sessions', registrations: 'users/registrations' }

  resources :users
end
```

**Generated Routes**

```
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)        users/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)        users/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)       users/sessions#destroy
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)   devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)  devise/passwords#edit
           user_password PATCH  /users/password(.:format)       devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)       devise/passwords#update
                         POST   /users/password(.:format)       devise/passwords#create
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)         users/registrations#cancel
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)        users/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)           users/registrations#edit
       user_registration PATCH  /users(.:format)                users/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                users/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                users/registrations#destroy
                         POST   /users(.:format)                users/registrations#create
---
                   users GET    /users(.:format)                users#index
                         POST   /users(.:format)                users#create
                new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)            users#new
               edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)       users#edit
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)            users#show
                         PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)            users#update
                         PUT    /users/:id(.:format)            users#update
                         DELETE /users/:id(.:format)            users#destroy
```

Comment: You can use devise_scope for your custom routes of `users`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: 'users/sessions', registrations: 'users/registrations' }

devise_scope :user do
  post   '/users/create'  => 'users#create',  as: :create_user
  get   '/users'  => 'users#index',  as: :list_users
  get   '/users/:id' => 'users#show', as: :show_user
end
```

or you can skip `create action` while defining `resources :users, except: :create` and make use of `registrations_controller` `create`.

Answer (score 1):

You can [configure the devise route](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-routes) to have a distinguishing path (ie. 'auth')

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, path: 'auth', controllers: { sessions: 'users/sessions', registrations: 'users/registrations' }
  resources :users
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need [this](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise#user-content-configuring-routes):

```
  devise_for :users, path: 'auth', controllers: {
    sessions: 'web/users/sessions',
    registrations: 'web/users/registrations'
  }
```